# bottom-border hover transition

Tags: css, effect

Can any one tell me how to do a `border-bottom` hover effect from bottom to top?

[image]

Src: http://www.sony.com/electronics/playstation

Comment: Hi. Do you have some html and css code which your working with you can post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple sample using the `pseudo` element `::after`

The advantage using this in favor of the `border-bottom`, it will not move the element up and down

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
a::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
a:hover::after {
  height: 5px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

a + a::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

a + a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<a> Hover me </a> <a> Hover me 2 </a>
```